Jensen's inequality: are there missing details from the hypothesis?
I'm trying to prove Jensen's inequality for an exercise, that is: having $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, continuous, I want to prove $e^{\int_0^1 f(x) dx} \leq \int_0^1 e^{f(x)} dx$.
I think that I got stuck in the proof because I tried to use the fact that $ax + b \leq e^x$ where the equality only holds at a tangent point $x^*$, and due to this, applying the integral to both:
$$\int_0^1 ax + b\ dx \leq \int_0^1 e^x dx$$
I then would replace $x \mapsto f(x)$. But then I don't know how to proceed to prove that $\int_0^1 e^{f(x)}\ dx \geq e^{\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx}$
Also, those doubts arose:

Is this true only for functions $f$ defined as $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ or even for a generic $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$?

Does the continuity hypothesis of $f$ suffice? Wouldn't I need something more, like positivity of $f$? Or maybe even that $f$ should be an increasing function?


Also I know that somehow, somewhere, I should take into account the convexity of $e^x$, but it doesn't sound stable to me: $e^x$ is convex, ok. But only knowing $f$ is continuous, how can I say $e^{f(x)}$ is convex too?

$e^{f(x)}$ is not necessarily convex. To answer your questions: The answer to the first one is yes, as long as $[a, b] \supseteq [0, 1]$. And continuity does indeed suffice. You don't even need continuity. Do you know Riemann sums? I think they might be useful for that proof. And do you know Jensen's inequality for sums?

The crucial facts are that the exponential is convex and continuous and, crucially, that an integral on $[0,1]$ is a limit of convex combinations.
Namely, a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 f$ is of the form
$$
\sum_k \Delta_k\,f(x_k),
$$
where $\sum_k\Delta_k=1$ and $\Delta_k\geq0$ for all $k$. Then, if $\gamma$ is convex,
$$
\gamma\Big(\sum_k \Delta_k\,f(x_k)\Big)\leq \sum_k \Delta_k\,\gamma\big(f(x_k)\big).
$$
If $\gamma$ is also continuous, taking limit we get
$$
\gamma\bigg(\int_0^1 f\bigg)\leq\int_0^1\gamma\circ f.
$$

Thank you! So this is why I don't need more hypothesis on $f$, like positivity and or monotony?

You don't need hypotheses on $f$, other than what is needed for the integral to exist.
